# Ranking Order Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ranking

I am analyzing my capstone data - I had students, from different grades, rate 6 feedback forms from 1-6, where 1 was the most helpful feedback type and 6 the least helpful feedback type. Is there a statistical test I can run to assess whether there are differences in ranking order by grade? Is there a test that looks at the rating order as a whole or do I need to run 6 ANOVAs (one per feedback type)?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is build a single model with both Feedback and Grade (and their interaction) as independent variables.  So in R notation, you would have something like, `Rating ~ Feedback + Grade + Feedback:Grade`.  This will allow you to see if there is an effect of Grade overall, but also if there are differences among the different Feedbacks.  Perhaps most interesting, it will allow to inspect the interaction, to see if the ratings for the different Feedbacks are different among different grades.

This is analogous to a two-way anova.

However, because your Ratings are individual Likert-type items, a traditional anova is probably not applicable for this data.

The ideal approach would be to use ordinal regression. This is relatively easy in some software packages, [particularly R](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_11.html) †.

Another approach would be to conduct a nonparametric two-way "anova" using [ARTool](http://depts.washington.edu/madlab/proj/art/).  This is also relatively easy in R.

---

† Note: link to my own webpage.